# How to create a natural-looking line using css and maybe javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am attempting to create a natural-looking line, instead of the straight ones by computers. I currently am doing this:

CSS:

```
#line {
width: 600px;
height: 1px;
background-color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="line"></div>
```

But this will give me a straight line. Is there a way to accomplish a natural-looking line using css and javascript if necessary?

Thanks

Comment: As a human, draw the line (in paint/ scan it in)?

Comment: And what a "natural-looking" line? Can you provide an example?

Comment: a slightly curved line, not completely straight.

Comment: You could probably create an algorithm to draw one in a canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using css, you could draw anything. Suppose you have a div 100px x 100px. In this div you have 10000 div cells of 1px x 1px. You can change the colour of every cell to whatever you want using css, so you can even present an image.

Have a look at this website: http://neil.fraser.name/software/img2html/

You can upload the image and you will end up with html that presents this image. As you can see with the tux.jpg you get > 280kB in size in comparison to 3kB image. So as you can see it doesn't make sense. Neither does what you want to achieve.

Just draw the line, save it as an image and put it on your website.

EDIT:
you can also use canvas, like someone else mentioned, but it will not work with old browsers or the ones with js disabled. It's also a bit of overkill to use canvas for that..

Comment: but I want the line to have the same width as the whole page, so...

Comment: So now you know what question to ask...I will give you a hint, but nothing more, because you still didn't say what kind of line it will be. You can make an image, that you will repeat horizontally. If you make sure that the line ends up on the same height as it starts it will look just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/img). If you really wanted to do it in javascript, try using canvas like in [this awesome tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/).

**Edit**: My second link was wrong and looked pretty facetious. Sorry!

Comment: Dude, you either linked the wrong page, or you're mocking think123.

Comment: Fair enough, although I _do_ think it sounds like a PNG might be OP's best bet.

Comment: And my link _was_ wrong. Sorry...

Comment: Ah that's good. I removed the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions (image, SVG, canvas).  The easiest and most bulletproof is to just make an image in something like Illustrator (or, probably more likely... inkscape) and render that.

If you want something more scalable either program mentioned above will give you an SVG.

Skip canvas for this.

Comment: but I want the line to have the same width as the whole page, so...

Comment: SVG is vector based.  This means you can scale it almost arbitrarily and it will still look fine.

Comment: Don't think vector graphics would be the best option for this. Rendering something in a canvas might be better.

Comment: @Cameron - Huh?  This is exactly what vectors are for.  Canvas would require him to either load an image... or define what a 'naturalistic' looking line looks like in code.  That's just silly.

Comment: Because vector graphics creates straight lines. This is exactly what he wants to avoid.

Comment: @CameronMartin - I'm sorry, but that's just not correct in any way, shape or form.  I highly recommend you look up vector graphics, which are generally built on bezier curves.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that SVG is the best solution, although IE support is an issue. Programmatically drawing the line in canvas would definitely be the most _fun_ though!

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike They are built on vector primitives, which can be bezier curves, but also lines. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics#Typical_primitive_objects And I agree, canvas would be fun.

Comment: @CameronMartin - As I said, generally built on bezier curves.  I do not see how 'vector graphics creates straight lines' is correct.  That hasn't been the case since... Warnock invented postscript to drive laser printers in the early 80s (thereby founding Adobe).

Comment: @RichardTowers - Having used both extensively for large projects... I disagree.  SVG has far more power when written dynamically (and winds up being faster as well).  : )

Comment: My point was kind of `More Power == Easier == Less fun`.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were in the camp of those who believe that Canvas is somehow the be-all, end-all.  I'm a bit defensive about that since (as I have a fairly deep background in imaging) I think that the entire canvas spec is very limited, providing little more than a blit-like surface -- while SVG provides a layered display-postscript style surface with XML (and jQuery) addressing.  I really just find the fact that the mindset is all on the inferior Canvas to be really sad.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a library that uses divs to create lines. I used [this one](http://trickyscripter.com/examples/after/jsgraphics_e.htm) in the past, and it did the trick. I could improve it a little for ellipses.

But anyway, I used that because it was 2009 and HTML5 was still very far away. Now there are more modern ways to create the same effect.

Comment: I think this question, being this unclear, is making a big mess, but I wish to know the reason of the down-votes.